# Cant get Codeception to to work with wp_query on multisite

Tags: php, wordpress, codeception

I am trying to setup a test to count the number of a custom post in the db as the first step to a more robust test, but it's not working properly. Here's a copy of the test:

```
<?php
// codecept run wpunit RWA:CourseModelsTest

namespace RWA;

require_once get_template_directory() . '/models/course.php';

class CourseModelsTest extends \Codeception\TestCase\WPTestCase {
    /**
     * @var \WpunitTester
     */
    protected $tester;

    protected function _before() {

    }

    protected function _after() {
    }

    // tests
    public function testSomeFeature() {

        $query = \Course::count();
        $this->assertEquals( 53, $query );
    }
}
```

Inside my model, here is what the function looks like

```
public static function count() {
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'offset' => 0,
        'post_type' => 'courses',
        'suppress_filters' => true,
    );
    $query = new \WP_Query( $args );
    return count( $query->posts );
}
```

But when it gets to the assertion, it says that 53 is not equal to 0.

Locally I'm running a multisite wordpress instance, but I'm not sure if that is affecting the setup or if that's something extra I need to configure in codeception. Anybody have any ideas?

Update:
Here's a copy of some current config files i have:

```
paths:
tests: tests
output: tests/_output
data: tests/_data
support: tests/_support
envs: tests/_envs
actor_suffix: Tester
modules:
config:
    WPDb:
        dsn: 'mysql:host=%DB_HOST%;dbname=%DB_NAME%'
        user: '%DB_USER%'
        password: '%DB_PASSWORD%'
        dump: 'tests/_data/dump.sql'
        populate: true #import the dump before the tests
        cleanup: false #import the dump between tests
        url: '%WP_URL%'
        urlReplacement: true #replace the hardcoded dump URL with the one above
        tablePrefix: '%TABLE_PREFIX%'
        waitlock: 0
    WPBrowser:
        url: '%WP_URL%'
        adminUsername: '%ADMIN_USERNAME%'
        adminPassword: '%ADMIN_PASSWORD%'
        adminPath: '%WP_ADMIN_PATH%'
    WPFilesystem:
        wpRootFolder: '%WP_ROOT_FOLDER%'
        plugins: '/wp-content/plugins'
        mu-plugins: '/wp-content/mu-plugins'
        themes: '/wp-content/themes'
        uploads: '/wp-content/uploads'
    WPLoader:
        wpRootFolder: "%WP_ROOT_FOLDER%"
        dbName: "%TEST_DB_NAME%"
        dbHost: "%TEST_DB_HOST%"
        dbUser: "%TEST_DB_USER%"
        dbPassword: "%TEST_DB_PASSWORD%"
        tablePrefix: "%TEST_TABLE_PREFIX%"
        domain: "%WP_DOMAIN%"
        adminEmail: "%ADMIN_EMAIL%"
        title: "Test"
        theme: retirement-wealth-academy
        plugins: ['']
        activatePlugins: ['']
    WPWebDriver:
        url: '%WP_URL%'
        adminUsername: '%ADMIN_USERNAME%'
        adminPassword: '%ADMIN_PASSWORD%'
        adminPath: '%WP_ADMIN_PATH%'
        capabilities:
            browserName: "chrome"
            javascriptEnabled: true
            webStorageEnabled: true
            nativeEvents: true
extensions:
enabled:
    - Codeception\Extension\RunFailed
commands:
    - Codeception\Command\GenerateWPUnit
    - Codeception\Command\GenerateWPRestApi
    - Codeception\Command\GenerateWPRestController
    - Codeception\Command\GenerateWPRestPostTypeController
    - Codeception\Command\GenerateWPAjax
    - Codeception\Command\GenerateWPCanonical
    - Codeception\Command\GenerateWPXMLRPC
    - Codeception\Command\DbSnapshot
    - tad\Codeception\Command\SearchReplace
params:
- .env
```

And for my specific suite

```
actor: WpunitTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - WPLoader
        - \Helper\Wpunit
        - WPDb
```

I its not targeting the correct database, and I dont know what im doing wrong. I found a useBlog method in the module files of wploader, and a multisite option, but having trouble getting it to do what i want -- use wp_query on blog 2, through a class (the class im testing).

Comment: It's been a while for me,  but I think you  should be returning  **post_ count**  `return $query->post_count;`  from your count() function

Comment: Good suggestion, done = )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking through lots of documentation and github issues, I have solved the problem! The db dump I was using was quite large, and also I noticed after running the test, my posts and postmeta tables were missing all data(which explains a 0 return from the query). Using the populator to handle the sql loading in the WPDb module cleared a lot of this up. If your sql dump is large (mine is around 26 megs) you should be using the populator.

```
  WPDb:
    dsn: 'mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=ffwpcore_test'
    user: '%DB_USER%'
    password: '%DB_PASSWORD%'
    dump: 'tests/_data/dump.sql'
    populate: true #import the dump before the tests
    cleanup: false #import the dump between tests
    url: '%WP_URL%'
    urlReplacement: true #replace the hardcoded dump URL with the one above
    tablePrefix: '%TABLE_PREFIX%'
    waitlock: 0
    populator: '/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql  --host=localhost -uroot -proot $dbname < $dump'
```

I now got a return from the wp_query and can now develop my tests further.